# what type of begonia is this?

Tags: identification

and how can I identify different begonia types

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJxBD.jpg)[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like *Begonia maculata*, but as to which particular variety it's hard to say. There are several named varieties of this plant, such as B. 'Amelia'. There is another similar begonia commonly known as angel wings or cane Begonia - *Begonia coccinea*, but it has narrower, longer leaves. This link https://www.apartmenttherapy.com/begonia-plants-262335 has general information on some Begonia varieties.

Comment: thanks it has pinky leaves now I'm rather impressed with its progress